# can't add data in points.json using fetch method post

Tags: reactjs, json, post, fetch, components

I have a points.json where I have some initial data:
    `{ "points":[ { "name": "user1", }, { "name": "user2", }, { "name": "user3", }, { "name": "user4", }, { "name": "user5", } ] }`

now I want to add another object of name via fetch method post, but I want to set the name as the userName state which I have as states in my react component, but in console I have an error says:
ndle.js:119     POST http://localhost:3000/points 500 (Internal Server Error)
postPo
and this:
Unexpected token 'T', "TypeError:"... is not valid JSON

so I tried to create post points function, which I use in useefect in my react komponent and also created custom hook where I fetch data from this points.json. so this is component code:

```
`    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './CardGame.css'
import { useFetch } from "./hooks/useFetch";

export default function AppShuffleCard() {
const[didMount,setDidMount] = useState(false);
const[userName,setUserName]=useState("");
const[url,setUrl]=useState('http://localhost:3000/points');
const{data:points, isPending, error} = useFetch(url);//this is custom hook I wrote code below

useEffect(()=>{
    let userNameInput = prompt("Please enter your name:");
    setUserName(userNameInput);
},[])


useEffect(()=>{setDidMount(true)},[])

const postPoints = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/points', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({name:userName})
      });
      const content = await response.json();
      console.log(content);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


useEffect(()=>{
      postPoints();
},[didMount]);

return (
 <div className='AppContainer'>
    <div className='points'>
        <div>
            <p>points</p>
            {isPending && <div>Loading points...</div>}
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            <ol>
                {
                    points && points.map( (point, index) =>(
                        <li key={index}>
                            <h3>{point.name}</h3>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 };`
```

and this is a custom hook I've used to fetch data at first:
``import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

```
export const usePoints = (url)=>{
const[data,setData]=useState(null);
const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const fetchPointsData = async()=>{
        setIsPending(true);
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url, {signal: controller.signal});
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            const json = await response.json();
            setIsPending(false);
            setData(json);
            setError(null);
        } catch(err){
            if(err.name === "AbortError"){
                console.log("The fetch was aborted");
            }else{
                setIsPending(false);
                setError("Couldn't fetch the data");
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
    }
    fetchPointsData();
    return ()=>{
        controller.abort();
    }
  },[url])

 return {data, isPending, error}
 }``
```